# Is there a way to programatically launch the Windows "set up microphone"

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, windows-xp, microphone

If I search for "microphone" in Windows 7 the first option is "Set up Microphone".

I'd like to be able to launch that programatically. I've tried dragging that shortcut to the desktop but it's just a "search" shortcut.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `"%SystemRoot%\System32\Speech\SpeechUX\SpeechUXWiz.exe"  MicTraining` but it is **undocumented**.

Comment: Oh, didn't know about the SpeechUXWiz.exe... I was always going the longer way: `rundll32.exe "%windir%\system32\speech\speechux\SpeechUX.dll", RunWizard MicTraining`

Comment: @Clay just run the wizard and check the command line in the task manager.

Comment: Both of the above versions work (starting from %systemroot% and %windir% for WINDOWS VISTA and 7 but not XP.

Comment: The project's Platform target setting must be AnyCPU, Prefer 32-bit unticked.